# What are uBlock Origin hotkeys?

Tags: ublock-origin

uBlock Origin certainly has hotkeys, as I've invoked the program accidentally by pressing keys and [the developer has participated in a related discussion on the Github page](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/issues/2870#issuecomment-322234217).

In particular a hotkey for the [element picker](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Element-picker) would improve workflow as I already have thousands of cosmetic and network filters.

Answer (score 10):

## Firefox:

Open the "Manage Extension Shortcuts" page within the Firefox Add-ons Manager (`about:addons`) to customize the shortcuts for uBlock Origin and other extensions:

[image: Firefox Add-ons Manager]

Note that native Firefox shortcuts cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 9):

## For Chromium or Chrome:

Now you can add custom shortcut from extensions page.

Go to: `Menu -> More Tools -> Extensions`.

[image]

Click on left menu button and `Keyboard Shortcuts`.

Find `uBlock` and assign your shortcut like below screenshot:

[image]